# Universal app design 1 table view that opens different view on cell click depending if on iPad or iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, universal-binary

I'm making a universal app and I've run across a situation I'm stumped on. On the iPad I'm using a split view, and I would like to make a `UITableViewController` that is shared on both the iPad and iPhone. I did that, but now when the user clicks a table cell I need to respond. On the iPhone I will init a new view controller and push it in the `UINavigationController` stack, but on the iPad I will init a different `UIViewController` and display it in the detail view pane. I know how to do each of these actions by its self, but how do I write the `UITableViewController` so that it knows which action to preform depending if its the iPhone or iPad?

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did in that exact same situation.

The table-view controller had a property called `detailViewController`. If this property is not `nil` than I updated that view based on what cell was touched. If that property was `nil` I must be on the iPhone and inside a `UINavigationViewController`. I use `self.navigationController` to push my new iPhone view.